# Is it possible to insert items at top of a ListView / ListAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

While maintaining the current position in the ListView?

I'm trying to create a sort of "calendar-like" ListView that starts on the current month, and allows the user to scroll upward back in time, one month at a time, infinitely.

I've found setStackFromBottom() method in ListAdapter, but that still creates the views with indices (positions) from top to bottom.

I think I need to find a way to either create a ListAdapter that uses some sort of a queue rather than position indexes, or a ListAdapter that starts with the position at the bottom and works it's way upward.

Thanks ahead for any assistance!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a listadapter you probably have a java collection for holding the underlying data. In this collection (lets say it's a list) you can insert new stuff using `add(int position, object data)` so you just have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged) in your adapter and everything should work fine.

Comment: Will calling notifyDataSetChanged() affect the current scroll position at all?  If not, then this is exactly what I needed!  I'll be trying this in just a bit!